# Como faço para obter o valor do parâmetro enviado por uma view e persistí-lo no banco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Quando aciono minha *action* cadastrar endereço, ela pega o `codigoCliente`,
manda por parâmetro `master/CadastrarEndereco?codigoCliente=1011`.

Como persistir o endereço do cliente escolhido?

Minhas *actions*:

```
        public ActionResult CadastrarEndereco(int codigoCliente)
        {
            var endereco = new Endereco();
            endereco.CodigoCliente = codigoCliente;

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CadastrarEndereco(EnderecoViewModel enderecoVM)
        {                
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              var endereco = Extentions.MapearEndereco(enderecoVM);

              endereco.CodigoCliente = codigoCliente;    
              EnderecoRepositorio.Cadastrar(endereco);
              EnderecoRepositorio.Commit();                                                                                      
            }

            return View(enderecoVM);    
        }
```

Comment: por que tu não retorna para sua view um tipo EnderecoViewModel em vez de Endereco ? Aí deixa num input hidden o código do Cliente, quando vir no Post, terá o código do Cliente

Comment: Como funciona o seu negócio? Você tem um cadastro de Cliente e cada cliente tem um endereço (que eh mais comum de acontecer)? Ou você tem um cadastro de Endereços? Sua dúvida está em pegar o parâmetro ou em como persistir no banco? Enfim, nos dê mais informações sobre a funcionalidade que você está desenvolvendo para tentarmos ajudar.

Comment: beleza!tenho um cadastro de clientes onde eu cadastro e populo uma grid ,na minha grid eu tenho os dados do cliente e um campo endereco,no campo endereco eu tenho um link cadastrar endereco, ao lado de cada cliente inserido,o link direciona a uma view de cadastro de endereco,passando justamente por parametros o  CodigodoCliente na qual, eu quero inserir um endereco. o Problema é que: nao consigo persistir meus dados no banco ,justamente porque minha view nao estar obtendo esse valor do CodigodoCliente para inserir no banco de dados

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta a declaração do *ViewModel* usado no *Controller*?

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente tem um ***Model*** com os campos do seu cadastro, por exemplo CadastroViewModel:

```
public class CadastroViewModel
{
    //Propriedades para cadastro do cliente....
    public int CodigoCliente { get; set; }
}
```

No seu ***Controller***, uma *action* *Get* será responsável por exibir a tela/*View* com o formulário para o usuário informar os dados. Nessa *action* **você precisa preencher o codigoCliente** (ou forçar o usuário a preencher antes de clicar no link), exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar()
{
    var codigoClienteGerado = GerarCodigoCliente();
    var cadastroViewModel = new CadastroViewModel() { 
                                       CodigoCliente = codigoClienteGerado 
                                   };
    return View(cadastroViewModel);
}
```

Na sua ***View***, você pode usar um *ActionLink*, passando o codigoCliente como parâmetro e direcionar para a *View* de cadastro do endereço assim:

```
@model CadastroViewModel
...
@Html.ActionLink("Cadastrar Endereço", "CadastrarEndereco", "NomeDoSeuController", new 
{
    codigoCliente = model.codigoCliente
})
```

Comment: @Hans Miller a resposta foi útil?